# how to add Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage assembly in powershell script

Tags: powershell, constructor, azure-storage, new-object

```bsh
Add-Type -Path c:\AzureStorageFile\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll

$AzStorObject = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext
```

Gives me error

> `New-Object` : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext`.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.commands.storage.azurestoragecontext.-ctor) the parameterless constructor for `AzureStorageContext` is not public.  There is a [`New-AzureStorageContext` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestoragecontext), however, that outputs `AzureStorageContext` instances.

Comment: can you please be a little more specific? I want to create an object of type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the `-ArgumentList` parameter to `New-Object`, so when attempting to instantiate the specified type it will look for a constructor that takes no parameters.  The parameterless constructor of the [`AzureStorageContext` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.commands.storage.azurestoragecontext.-ctor) is `protected`, not `public`, though...

> ```cs
> protected AzureStorageContext ();
> ```

...so `New-Object` will not be able to invoke it.

That same `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll` assembly is used by the [`Azure.Storage` package](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure.Storage/).  Upon installing that...

```bsh
Install-Module -Name Azure.Storage
```

...you can invoke the [`New-AzureStorageContext` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestoragecontext) to create `AzureStorageContext` instances...

```bsh
$AzStorObject = New-AzureStorageContext # Additional parameters needed
```

Otherwise, there is a `public` constructor of the `AzureStorageContext` class...

> ```cs
> public AzureStorageContext (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount account);
> ```

...that you could use if you pass a `CloudStorageAccount` instance...

```bsh
$AzStorObject = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext -ArgumentList $myCloudStorageAccount
```